# External tables querying from Google Drive

Tags: import

As the .xls file is saved, how do I query from BigQuery without importing the file ?

Not in devolepment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a federated data source following these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-sources

It is best you upload the XLS into google drive and then import from there.

If you use a XLS it will be converted into a google sheet.

[image]

Comment: So the XLS file is compressed into a google sheet using google drive API. There must be some alternative to this. I'll look into it in the future, thank you!